# Can I install Windows 7 64-bit with 16GB to run more 32-bit apps at once?

Tags: windows-7, memory, 64-bit

At work, I have the option to have the 64-bit version of Windows 7 with 16GB installed. The best benefit I can think of is that Windows 7 64-bit can utilize memory beyond 4GB. One of my colleagues said even if I install Windows 7 64-bit, the 32-bit apps will not be able to address all the memory. That confused me and wasn't sure it that means that only 64-bit apps can run in the memory space between 4GB to 16GB. If I run 10 32-bit apps using 1GB each, I should be able to do this without paging right?

Comment: Your colleague is correct a 32-bit applocation cannot use more then 4GB of memory.  You can use 16GB of memory any way you want.

Comment: How exactly?  It's an answer to your question. A 64-bit application could use 1GB or 16GB

Comment: Okay, that is more clear. Combining your two comments makes more sense to me.

Comment: Why the down votes?  This is a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Every program runs in its' own virtual memory space. These are allocated in 1MB chunks as the program requests memory from the OS. The programs see this memory as one large, contiguous block of memory (the so-called "flat memory model."). This was different than the older 16-bit model "segmented memory" model, where two registers would combine into a single 20- or 32-bit memory address, depending on the memory controller's current operating mode.

Each 32-bit program will be limited to 2GB of total usable memory; the memory area starting at 0x20000000 is used for DLLs in 32-bit applications. It is true that a *single individual* 32-bit app will not be able to access all 16GB of memory, because it's not all addressable. However, each program starts near the bottom of its virtual memory block (close to 0x00000000), and those are offset by the virtual memory manager to the actual physical location in RAM, so in that sense, the 32-bit program can reside anywhere in physical memory. Conceptually, this means that you could fill all 16GB of RAM with nothing but 32-bit programs.

Both 32- and 64-bit apps can run side by side, and be located anywhere in RAM. Note that paging happens before memory is exhausted, so it is still unlikely you could run 16 1GB RAM apps without paging happening. The system tries to keep some physical memory free, and also uses that as a cache for disk reads and writes.

Note that even 32-bit OSs *can* access more than 4GB of memory, although each individual app is still limited to 4GB. This is because of a relatively old technology known as PAE (Physical Address Extension). 32-bit Windows doesn't let you access memory above 2GB/4GB as a matter of licensing, but 32-bit versions of Linux would happily run on a 16GB system with full access to the memory installed. Some 32-bit versions of Windows Server could also access more than 4GB of memory: "Windows Server 2008 Datacenter" could use up to 64GB of RAM on a 32-bit processor.

Comment: You state a 32-bit application can only access 2GB except that isn't the case.  What does Linux have to do with the authors question?

Comment: @Ramhound what is true then?

Comment: A 32 bit app, in Windows, only has 2GB available to it, because the other 2GB it could access is reserved for the OS. Linux was only mentioned to make a point about memory limitations on 32 bit OSes.

Comment: Well on a 64-bit operating a 32-bit process can use up to 4GB not 2GB

Comment: Question has nothing to do about 32-bit operating systems

Comment: I feel phyrfox commentary about 32-bit OS is relevant because I wrote about the benefits of going beyond 4GB. He also addresses the 4GB memory limitation is not due to being a 32-bit OS. Personally, I'd be more happy if I could utilize 32-bit OS with 16GB of memory so I can keep my current peripherals and not have to hunt for 64-bit drivers of all printers, webcam, etc.

Comment: I did specify that the program only gets to use 2gb. Yes, all 4gb is accessible, but half of that is still reserved by the system. No single 32 bit Windows app can actually use more than 2gb for itself, regardless of the underlying Windows operating mode.

Comment: Why the down votes?  This answer is more or less correct.  The only fault I can point out is that memory is allocated in 4 KiB pages, not 1 MiB at a time, and I'm not sure what MS has done with their silly licencing restrictions on various flavors of windows today, but NT used to have a boot.ini option to move the user/kernel split to 3/1 GiB so 32 bit applications could use up to 3 GiB per process.

Comment: Seems silly then for a consumer os, windows 7 32-bit couldn't be designed to recognize and utilize more than 4gb. Gawd, here I was thinking windows 7 64-bit was require to exceed the 4gb barrier, but it's just Microsoft being Microsoft again.

Comment: 64-bit versions of Windows have the `/3GB` switch always enabled. There’s also stuff like AWE. I suggest editing the answer and trimming out all the non-SOHO stuff, because it gets complicated fast and inaccuracies arise. [Official info](https://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=889654) on all this.

Comment: There is no switch but in effect it's a /4GB switch: 32-bit processes do have access to up to 4 GB. This is easy to demonstrate with the `testlimit64` tool from the Windows Internals "book tools". Half of the 4 GB is not "reserved by the system" on a 64-bit Windows system; it's a 64-bit OS and it lives at addresses well above 0xFFFFFFFF. I would also point out that virtual address space is almost never allocated "contiguously", and DLLs don't necessarily start at any particular address, on either 32- or 64-bit systems. The sysinternals VMmap tool will show this.